# APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY AND PROMINENT DISCLOSURE

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I have received this email from Google console in a beta release. I have been using Firebase since 2017, and until now it have not be a problem.

> Your app is uploading users' Installed Packages information
>   to https://app-measurement.com without a prominent disclosure. Make
>   sure to also post a privacy policy in both the designated field in the
>   Play Developer Console and from within the Play distributed app
>   itself.

What could I do, based on your experience?

Comment: Please convert the title to mixed case

Comment: May [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149753/2289835) help you.

Answer (score 2):

I've received the same message from the Google Play store three days ago. I've done a little digging as I was interested in the app-measurement.com (which returns 404 when visited).

The domain is registered by MarkMonitor Inc. and is using Google name servers. It's mentioned as Google Analytics helper [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54463682/8835675).

Anyway I've updated the Firebase libs and submit the next update which was marked as 'fine' by Google Play.

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.1")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1")
```

For me the the Privacy policy was not mentioned, so maybe add this as well (I'm already having mine).

Comment: I've also received the same kind of warning form google paly about Facebook SDK. Do I have to remove the FB SDK or is there any possible solution?
Question link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135362/your-app-uploading-installed-packages-information-to-https-graph-facebook-com