# My app was rejected from Google Play "APK REQUIRES PROMINENT DISCLOSURE"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

my app got rejected from the google play store due to the following reason:

> APK REQUIRES PROMINENT DISCLOSURE
>   Your app is uploading users' [Installed packages]  information to [https://app-measurement.com/a] without a prominent disclosure. Prior to the collection and transmission, it must prominently highlight how the user data will be used, describe the type of data being collected and have the user provide affirmative consent for such use.

as I know, app-measurement.com is firebase analytics end point and we do use it, but we most definitly do not upload the users "installed packages".
my guess is that one of our 3rd party packages might be doing that, but I have no idea how to find out, and the notice I got from google does not give away any more details.
help will be much appriciated!

Comment: could you list all 3rd party SDks that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

There may be multiple reasons for it. I am explaining as per my experience.

**1. Check other tracks:** Apart from the production track, check into other tracks as well.

i.e: **Internal / Closed / Open testing** track or any custom track you created. Each track must comply with the policy. In our case, there was an abandoned old **Closed Testing** track. I created a release for that track and it worked. Please note: We can not delete the "Internal / Closed / Open testing track". It's not fair but we have no option to delete it and we have to keep that track updated.

Google response:[image: deactive closed testing track]

**2. Fix the policy issues:** Your privacy policy page must clearly explain how user's each data is **collected or shared** by the application. Especially phone number, email, name, etc. For example, you can find the privacy policy page in the ["Developer contact" section of our application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emedstore_subscription).

**3. Insert privacy policy:** Provide proper and valid privacy policy URL in play store console.

> Play store Console > Select your app > Policy and programs > App content > Privacy policy

**4. Adequate prominent disclosure:**
Apart from privacy policy, there should be prominent disclosure before using any of the user's data. Information should be simple, readable, and clear. For more information, have a look at [Best practices for prominent disclosure and consent.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11150561)

Prominent disclosure example:

[image]

**:OTHER POSSIBLE REJECTION REASON:**

**5. Data safety:**

> Play store Console > Select your app > Policy and programs > App content > Data safety

Need to declare each data type collected or shared by the application.

**6. Cardinal Mobile SDK usage:** Application or any dependencies must use an updated version of Cardinal Mobile SDK. In our case [paypal-android-checkout-sdk](https://github.com/paypal/android-checkout-sdk/issues/174) was using the Cardinal mobile SDK. We just updated it to the latest version.

Google response:
[image: Cardinal Mobile SDK]

**7. Action requested: Declare your Ad ID permission:**
For more information, you can have a look at [this S.O. answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73132765/2289835)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a privacy policy outlining what data you collect and who you share it with. You then have to add it to your store listing on the Google Play Console. In your app you will have to add a consent screen which shows the privacy policy and requires the user to press an "Accept Privacy Policy" button.

Answer (score 0):

If your application comes under any of these headings you will have to submit a privacy policy notice to any user:

> - If your app collects personal data from users under the age of 13, you'll need to comply with COPPA or Data Protection Act etc depending on your country
> - If your app collects personal data from minors (under the age of 18), comply with the Content Eraser law.
> - If you collect personal data from students, comply with the SOPIPA law
> - If you are using remarketing/retargeting tracking code with Google AdWords or AdRoll or any other third-party, you'll need to update the
>   the Privacy Policy to inform users about this practice.

If you do fall under this, then you will have to create a policy.
to do this:
Follow these steps to add the Privacy Policy URL to your Google Play Store app listing:

Log into your Google Play Developer Console. If you don't have an account, create one first.

- Select All Applications
- Select the application
- Click Store Listing
- Go to the Privacy Policy field
- Enter the URL where you host the policy. *You must host the policy on your website*.
- Click Save