# How to solve APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY​?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-release

my app was publish on CH play 1 year ago. but today I got a mail from Google Play

APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY​
Your app is uploading users **Contact list & files** information  without posting a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.

my AndroidManifest file already defines like this, also define policy on play console like this.

enter image description here

any way to fix this

Comment: You need to add a privacy policy clearly explaining why you are uploading the contacts of those users.

Comment: where can i explain it? Is it in Privacy policy on Play console?

Comment: In your Privacy Policy & add the policy's url in your developer dashboard.

Comment: @DarShan do you have template for this

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149753/2289835) is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following things -

**Google Play updated Privacy Policy Guidelines -**

1. I think your app contains a Contact list & file information, So according to new policy guidelines you need to create a privacy policy URL with the information of all permission you are using in the app.
2. Also you need to show the Term & Policy link in-app as well with a checkbox to accept It while registration/login of a user.
3. You need to fill Data Safety form from App Content section in Play Console.

Comment: do you have template for url information of all permission?

Comment: You can check the privacy policy for any app --> let's say linked in https://www.linkedin.com/legal/privacy-policy --> Check the session --> 1. Data We Collect

Answer (score 1):

1- Just add privacy policy link on startup screen with checkbox for accepting terms&condition.

---

2- Add privacy policy link on app home sceen.