# app rejected due to: Prominent disclosure Non compliant design for policy: Accessibility API

Tags: android, google-play, accessibility, google-play-console, policy

I received mail from google play after releasing new update for my application saying that your app app is rejected due to  following reasons:

**Issue found: Prominent disclosure Non compliant design**

**Issue found: Insufficient prominent disclosure**

**Issue found: Missing prominent disclosure**

I have already added Prominent disclosure before asking the Accessibility permission like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/15BYw.png

still app is rejected with the same reason. not able to understand what else i need to change

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello @VikramParimi thank you for your comment, i need help to understand why my app is getting reject even i have made changes according to  policy and Prominent disclosure Non compliant design as well but still they rejected with same reason , not able to understand what else i need to change.

Comment: Have you answered the questionnaire in App Content section on Google Play console to declare all the permissions?

Comment: @VikramParimi yes i have  declare all of that in previous production release, and it was approved, and update  was available on play store  as well but  my latest was rejected. I have not changed any things related to the permissions used in my app.

Comment: You can have a look at [this S.O. answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149753/2289835) for prominent disclosure rejection issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submitting appeal, support team replied that i have to resubmit  permission declaration with new video this resolved my issue.