# App got rejected by Google play - APK REQUIRES PROMINENT DISCLOSURE​

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-console

Your app is uploading users' **Installed Application** information to https://cloudconfig.googleapis.com without disclosing it in the privacy policy in Play Console.

I have searched in my project but there is no trace of the collecting the data using the link, indeed I use firebase SDK. Expecting a reason for rejection, when we use the same google products in our projects.

Comment: Some components of the Firebase SDKs depend on Google Play Services, which Google requires that you disclose in your privacy policy. The list of the components that use Google Play Services is [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#google-play-services-required-recommended). Analytics, Cloud Messaging and Dynamic Links are the common culprits. The docs also have a section on [Google Play data disclosure requirements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/play-data-disclosure).

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149753/2289835) is useful.