# Your app uploading Installed Packages information to https://graph.facebook.com without a prominent disclosure

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

Google Play rejected my update due to this, I'm using SDK version 5.5.1. I also tried updating to the new version and disabling auto event logging but that didn't help and app my app got rejected the second time?

**Edit:** I tried with the latest version (6.3.0) and that's also got rejected.

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled"
        android:value="false" />
```

Since Google doesn't allow this, Is there anything I can do from here?

[image]

Comment: Which facebook sdks are you using?

Comment: @JensV I'm using Facebook SDK (v 5.5.1) with the following modules:
1. Facebook Login 
2. FB event tracking
3. Deferred Dee-link 
4. FB App-links 
5. Share/invite

If that's what you're asking.

Comment: Did you mention access to installed apps (and also phone or contact book data if you're accessing them) in your Privacy Policy? For example, "information to installed apps is being uploaded to graph.facebook.com for debugging purposes only".

Comment: @vmayorow No, I haven't mentioned this info in privacy policy because we were not using it.

Comment: @vmayorow Also, why should I add anything in my privacy policy if I'm not collecting or using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason not because of Facebook SDK, It probably because you may be having webpage's which will collect some user information.

In order to get it to approve from play store, you should have

- have a website page with a privacy policy that states what data
  you're collecting
- have a button in your app's UI that will link to said
  privacy policy or show a screen that shows what data you're
  collecting.

Hope this helps

Comment: But they (google play console) clearly mention that it's (install app data) getting recorded on graph.facebook.com also can web pages record this kind of data?

Comment: graph.facebook.com loading anywebpage? @Ankit. If so than you should write it in privacy policy for what purpose are you using that